# Set the SelectedText of a ComboBox in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Heyo its me again,

```
<ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding EnterpriseList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Enterprise, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EnterpriseIsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Margin="3" Grid.Column="1">
```

does anyone know how i can bind the SelectedItem in this example to an Enterprise-Object?
I can select the enterprise in the combobox like I want it, and it delivers a enterprise-object too, but when i reload the view, the text of the combobox doesnt get set to the name of the enterprise-object.

I hope I have explained my problem well enough, my english is not that good, I usually speak german ...

Comment: try setting 'SelectedValuePath' to Name

Comment: Tried this already, doesnt work ... I debugged it and the Enterprise-object is the one I want, but the name doesnt get loaded in the combobox and I dont know why ...

Comment: What do you mean, when you reload the view? Do you leave it? if yes, do you save the state somewhere? What is selectedIndex when you leave form and what is selectedIndex when you re-enter form?

Comment: Please post your code that sets the Enterprise and EnterpriseList source properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML look ok. Please be aware that the item your assign to `Enterprise` must be one from the list `EnterpriseList`. The Combobox does compare object references not object contents e.g. the characters of strings.